# Unity and multiple EF contexts per app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container

We currently use Unity for our Windows Services and MVC apps and it works fine.
We create a ChildContainer for each web request and define the DbContext injection as hierarquical, so each web request has its own instance of the context.
We also have a BaseDbContext class that makes sure the EF settings are consistent throughout all of our contexts.

So far so good.
The problem now is the addition of a second database and, therefore, a second context that also inherits from BaseDbContext.

We can't configure Unity to inject different contexts, since the base class is the same.

The solution we found was to create a *ContextProvider where T : BaseDbContext* and register that in Unity, so we can differentiate the context by the type.

However, this doesn't seem right, since Unity should be able to handle this scenario.

What are suggested approaches to handle this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two registrations of the same type, using named registrations:

```
Container
  .RegisterType<BaseDbContext>("context1", ...)
  .RegisterType<BaseDbContext>("context2", ...)
```

And, in the client code:

```
public void MyClass {

   public MyClass([Dependency("context1")] BaseDbContext context1, 
                  [Dependency("context2")] BaseDbContext context2) {
         ....
   }
}
```